# Need to capture patterns and replace code in file VBScripts

Tags: regex, vbscript, filesystemobject

The code in file abc is which needs to captured with Regex.

```
With TeWindow("tewindow").Tescreen("something").TeField("some")
 .set "value"
 .setToProperty "V"
 .exist(0)
End With
```

This code should be replaced in abc with

```
'With TeWindow("tewindow").Tescreen("something").TeField("some")
myset("something_some"), "value"
mysetToProperty("something_some"), ""
myExist("something_some"), (0)
'End With
```

Following is the trial so far. I'm not able to make it to writing in the file.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set testfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\test\testout4.txt", 1, True)
line = testfile.ReadAll
testfile.Close

sString = line

pat = "with[\s]{1,}tewindow\((.*?)\).tescreen\((.*?)\).tefield\((.*?)\)"  '12
pat1 = "^\.[a-zA-Z]{1,}"

Call DeclareRegEx(objRE,pat)

If objRE.test(sString) Then
  Set Matches = objRE.Execute(sString)
  Set match = Matches(0)

  intcount = match.SubMatches.Count

  If intcount > 0 Then
    For I = 1 To intcount-1
      'If i = intcount-1 Then
      objRef = objRef & match.SubMatches(I)
    Next
  Else  '30
    objRef = objRef & match.SubMatches(I) & "_"
  End If
End If

call DeclareRegEx(objRE1, pat1)
If objRE1.Test(sString) Then
  Set Matches1 = objRE1.Execute(sString)
  For Each Match1 in Matches1
    RetStr1 = Match1.Value
    strplc = Right(RetStr1, Len(RetStr1) - 1)
    actual =  objRE1.Replace(RetStr1, "my" & strplc & "(" & objRef & ")")

    MsgBox actual
  Next
End If

Function DeclareRegEx(obj, pattern)
  Set obj = New RegExp
  obj.Global = True
  obj.Multiline = True
  obj.Pattern = pattern
  obj.IgnoreCase = True
End Function
```

Suggestion for some other approach or regex is welcome.

Comment: Try a verbose approach, create the expression for this kind of input and use a simple replacement pattern with backreferences - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vfo9Bk/1). Do not forget that you need to double `"` to use them in a VBA string literal and instead of `\n`, use `vbCrLf`.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew -  failed to capture multi line , \n or vbcrlf doesn't work..

Comment: No, it does not. You failed to define the regex properly.

Comment: can you provide the regex ? please try with VBscript . appreciate your help!

Comment: I already provided a demo. All you need is to correctly use the data in your code.

Answer (score 0):

well as the approach of finding the block , being captured by verbose regex is not seemed to be a generic in the code i tried something like the following..

1. take the file content into an array 
   2.find the line no of with and end with 
   3.run a loop to iterate the functions from the next line of the with till line before the end with.

it worked for me !